# Specifying concrete types instead of var

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got the following piece of code which gives the error `cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type object`

```
protected void btnMakeCards_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("spDrugCardGenerator", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        foreach (var row in dt.Rows)
        {
            foreach (var col in dt.Columns)
            {
                Response.Write(row[col].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it that this code compiles fine if I use the concrete types of `DataRow` and `DataColumn`?  The compiler can infer what the data type should be in the using statements.  What's the deal with the data table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `DataTable.Rows` returns a `DataRowCollection`. The `DataRowCollection`'s `GetEnumerator` method only returns `IEnumerable`,, not a generic `IEnumerable<T>`. So the type that is inferred is `object`.

Obviously, you can't call an indexer method on `object`.

EDIT:

As commented by user7116, `var` will just "accept" that you want whatever it can infer. Whereas, using the actual type produces an underlying cast. This is the generated IL:

```
callvirt instance object [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerator::get_Current()
               // ^^^^^^ returned as an object
castclass [System.Data]System.Data.DataRow // only included if you 
                                           // supply DataRow in the foreach
```

Which results in the expected behaviour.

Comment: It is worth noting that `foreach (X x in y)` will generate a cast from `y.GetEnumerator().Current` to `X`, whereas `var` "accepts" what it is given.

Comment: Obviously, if u set explicitly the foreach variable type to DataRow (instead of implicitly 'var'), each iteration make an automatic cast from object to DataRow type.

Comment: @T-moty: it wasn't obvious in this case apparently.

Comment: @user7116 Included that in my answer. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: @user7116: Yes, i've fall in this trap too: maybe System.Data namespace have an old concept (maybe .Net 1.1), without generic types.

Answer (score 2):

The DataTable's rows and columns collections are `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable` of `<T>`, so they indeed return `object`s because they're not generic.

You can deal with the former by using the DataTable.AsEnumerable extension method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`dt.Rows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows.aspx), which is a `DataRowCollection`, implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. This means that when you do `foreach (var row in dt.Rows)`, `var` can only resolve to `object`. Here are two of your options, which each just cast the objects to the appropriate data types:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        Response.Write(row[col].ToString());
    }
}
// or
foreach (var row in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
{
    foreach (var col in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>())
    {
        Response.Write(row[col].ToString());
    }
}
```

If you *really* want to use an implicitly-typed `var`, you'd have to resort to something like this, which I do *not* recommend.

```
for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var row = dt.Rows[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        var col = dt.Columns[j];
        Response.Write(row[col].ToString());
    }
}
```

(this works because `DataRowCollection`'s [indexer property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.item.aspx) is strongly-typed)